# SQL limit gives bad results

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-limit

I have a problem with using SQL LIMIT statement. I have 21 records stored in database and I want to get results piecewise. I have written this query:

```
SELECT * FROM table JOIN another_table ON XXX = YYY WHERE XXX = ? ORDER BY col DESC LIMIT ?, ?
```

Here is num of rows which I get when I use this values:

```
LIMIT:  0 .. 10  --->  num of rows 10     -> Correct
LIMIT: 10 .. 20  --->  num of rows 11     -> Incorrect
LIMIT: 20 .. 30  --->  num of rows 0      -> Incorrect
```

Code is used in php function and for database operations I use PDOStatement class but this error is also manifested in the use of the MySQLi class.

Does anyone know where the problem is?

Comment: LIMIT doesn't take values like `LIMIT [from] [to]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you say:

```
LIMIT X, Y
```

You are saying `X` is the offset and `Y` is the count.  What you want is:

```
LIMIT 0, 10
LIMIT 10, 10
LIMIT 20, 10
```

or, use the `OFFSET` keyword and use:

```
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 10
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 20
```